# Why is it called "Dry Thrust"?

Tags: jet-engine, terminology, jet

When reading the specifications of a jet aircraft anywhere on the Internet, it usually states that its engine produces X pounds of "dry thrust".

Why is it called "Dry" Thrust? As opposed to what?

Comment: Some information about afterburners: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/what-is-an-afterburner-and-how-long-can-a-jet-fly-on-afterburner/17287#17287

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Dry thrust usually means the non-augumented thrust i.e. thrust without the use of afterburners or liquid injection. The maximum thrust produced by jet engines w/o afterburner is sometimes called military thrust.

The thrust of a jet eingine can be increased by using methods like water(+methonol) injection (mostly in older turbojet engines) or by using afterburners (reheat). In such cases, the (higher) thrust produced is called wet thrust.

Answer (score 7):

Dry thrust refers to an afterburning engine running without [afterburner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterburner).  The figures you mention usually refer to the maximum thrust without afterburner.

Answer (score 6):

One interesting case of actually wet thrust, as opposed to afterburners, is the [Harrier Jump Jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet), which can [inject water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Pegasus#Water_Injection) into its engines for up to 90 seconds to increase performance for vertical takeoff and landing without melting its turbine blades. The [use of water in jet engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_injection_(engine)#Use_in_aircraft) is interesting because it not only cools the turbine, but simultaneously adds thrust through the added mass and steam expansion.